# From External Code, How do I Get Access to DynamicCode without a Module?

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

I have a Content-Type in a custom 2sxc App (AppId = 10). The content type name is "SeasonSettings" which contains colors, fonts, icons, and images used to modified the site's theme a few times a year. There is no View or module, the client gets to the settings by going in to Admin for the app, Data tab, etc.

When trying to access this from my skin file's C# code in **Home.ascx**, I have the following:

```
// the details you need to know
var appId = 7;                     // The AppId that of the target Content Type
string ctName = "SeasonSettings";  // The name of the Content Type
int entityId = 2345;               // The EntityId of the item with our settings
 
// get a handle to the App
var app7 = ToSic.Sxc.Dnn.Factory.App(appId);
```

Now I am stuck. Since I don't have a module, I can't get a CmsBlock (BlockBuilder) which I need to get DynamicCode so I can use AsList, AsEntity, AsDynamic, etc.

So my next steps would be something like:

```
// this fails because "AsList" is unknown
var setting = AsList(app7.Data[ctName])
  .Where(e => e.EntityId == entityId)
  .First()
;
 
<p>Color: @setting.BgColor</p>
```

Without having to put a module/view on the page and using CmsBlock(tabId, moduleId) etc, is there another way from `app7` to get to DynamicCode or any way to call/use AsList()?

Answer (score 0):

As of now I don't think there is an easy way to do this, as dynamic code is meant to use in razor files and custom APIs.

I suggest you quickly create a hidden module somewhere these things initialized, and then get than block for further use.

Comment: I am sad now. ;)

But I understand, thank you!!

Comment: 6+ months later... Any change to this in v12? Any plans to make this possible in the future?

Comment: This should make it into v13 to be released this week... :)

Comment: I do not praise you often enough. :)

Comment: Note: we didn't make it by December - but it will be in v13.02 - https://docs.2sxc.org/net-code/external/dotnet-external-use.html